# mysql select query with dates not returning correct records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is supposed to pull records from several tables using a join, and filter all of them based on a date range. It seems to be pulling a random group of records  - it doesn't return all the records in the join, which I imagine it would if it were completely ignoring the dates, but the records it does pull don't match the date criteria.

Here's the query; I've tried it two different ways with the same result.

Option 1:

```
SELECT p.PurchActvtyID, p.PurchAmt, p.CcAuthCode, p.PurchDT,  v.VoucherNbr, 
 a1.name as billName, a1.company as billCompany, a1.address1
  FROM arrc_PurchaseActivity p
LEFT JOIN arrc_Voucher v  ON p.VoucherID = v.VoucherID
LEFT JOIN jos_customers_addresses a1 ON p.AcctID = a1.id
where v.TypeFlag='S'  or v.TypeFlag is null 
and p.PurchDT between '20101201000000' and '20101209235959' order by v.ActivatedDT asc
```

(In this case, we've programmatically added times to the starting and ending range to ensure we get every record from 12:01 AM on the start date to 11:59 PM on the end date.)

Option 2:

```
SELECT p.PurchActvtyID, p.PurchAmt, p.CcAuthCode, p.PurchDT,  v.VoucherNbr, 
  a1.name as billName, a1.company as billCompany, a1.address1                 
   FROM arrc_PurchaseActivity p
 LEFT JOIN arrc_Voucher v  ON p.VoucherID = v.VoucherID
 LEFT JOIN jos_customers_addresses a1 ON p.AcctID = a1.id
 where v.TypeFlag='S'  or v.TypeFlag is null 
 and p.PurchDT between '2010-12-01' and '2010-12-09' order by v.ActivatedDT asc
```

What I'm getting back is records with p.PurchDT equal to 2010-10-28 16:33:13, 2010-11-11 10:37:30, and several others. The good news is it is pulling in all records with dates between the ones indicated in the query; the bad news is it's randomly (from what I can tell) also pulling in other records that don't fit the criteria.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I could have sworn this code was working several weeks ago, but now it isn't, even though there haven't been any changes to it.

Comment: Pro tip: `BETWEEN` doesn't work very well for date ranges because the end of the range is inclusive.  `AND col >= startdate AND col < enddate + INTERVAL 1 DAY` gives everything between midnight on `startdate` and the very last moment of `enddate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because you need () in:

```
 where (v.TypeFlag='S'  or v.TypeFlag is null)
```

The results with incorrect dates would all have TypeFlags='S', right?

Additionally, if you use dates in the between, you should use the day next to the last that you want, otherwise, the last day would only include records with `PurchDT = 2010-12-09 00:00:00` and everything else from that day would be ignored - I guess.

Comment: I'll try the parens. All the results currently in the database have TypeFlag = S, so it's not a valid way to check for "incorrect results".  As far as the dates go, no - we specifically added the time value to the date fields in the query (see Option 1) to make sure that's it's getting everything from 12:01 AM on the first date through 11:59 PM on the second date.

Comment: you should check this, I guess - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Thanks; I'll keep that bookmarked from now on. Not sure why I've never had issues with not using parens before... I guess I've just been lucky. In any case, it seems like that did fix it.